# Make changes to (my own) already published IEEE paper?

Tags: publications, peer-review, ieee

The initial copy of IEEE paper that I had submitted required some changes which the conference convenor requested after reviewing.

So I made the changes and submitted again but the convenor accidently must have forwarded the original submission to IEEE and it got published. So how can get make necessary changes (to a published) IEEE paper. Please help!

Comment: I know one professor who keeps updated versions of all his papers on his web site.

Comment: But keeping updated version on personal website won't serve the purpose I think bro cause people might say updates are not peer reviewed... Maybe I'm wrong

Comment: If it is possible, you can update the paper on arxiv. Of course, this depends on the copyright agreement. Anyway, if it is the publisher's fault, please contact them right away. Check for example how many mistakes a publisher can do http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.118.049904.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the journal publish an **erratum**, if the changes are limited and bear on statements of fact. For example, if you inverted the array indices in proof 3, or a typo in lemma 2 changes its meaning, or you quoted from another paper and forgot the citation. The journal's web site will show a link to the update.

Otherwise, the published version is the version of record, and wholesale changes wouldn't normally be acceptable for two reasons. First, the journal would have to ask the reviewers (in this case, *ad hoc* reviewers for a conference with which the journal is not associated) to re-evaluate the manuscript. Second, other scientists may have already based work on the published version in good faith.

(An analogy, if you are a user of the `git` version control system, is forcing a push to a public repository. Don't be that person.)

If you can **substantially improve** the original by these changes, then it is worthwhile to make an updated version available through ArXiv or on an institutional archive. At least it will be indexed and will show up in searches. It is common to see this kind of update in CVs and publication lists.

If the changes are only cosmetic, or bear on things like citing existing work or improving figures, then my suggestion is to stick with the old version. Everybody has papers that they would have liked to improve, but couldn't. Save your energy for the next paper!

Comment: If changes were not made because of an error on the convenor's part, I suspect the journal would be willing to make much more substantial changes than they ordinarily would allow. There might be an erratum in the printed version, and probably a replacement of the online version (which is the only thing anybody looks at nowadays).